# Upgrading Subversion 1.5 to 1.6 on Debian 5

Tags: debian, svn, apt, debian-lenny

I would like to upgrade Subversion 1.5.1dfsg1-4 (from lenny) to 1.6.4dfsg-1~bpo50+1 (from lenny-backports) on my Debian 5 machine. Which steps do I need to take? Do I need to backup my repository, or can I just install the new package over the old one?

Comment: You may not need to do a backup, but why wouldn't you?  Particularly if you don't already have a regularly scheduled backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have backups of your repository anyways.  But if not I would make one before you upgrade.

However according to the [1.6 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html)

> There is no need to dump and reload your repositories. Subversion 1.6 can read repositories created by earlier versions. To upgrade an existing installation, just install the newest libraries and binaries on top of the older ones.

Comment: +1 complete and concise answer.